# Bandwidth from Vercel to AWS Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, vercel, data-transfer, cost-management

I am trying to understand how to connect Vercel to Dynamodb and save costs on Data transfer.
Is it possible to define VPC Between them? if vercel & dynamodb are in the same region, how much cost I will see from AWS Outside and Vercel inside?

I am expecting to know briefly the costs without surprices

Answer (score 0):

While Vercel [does run](https://vercel.com/blog/aws-and-vercel-accelerating-innovation-with-serverless-computing) on AWS; at this point it does not support access to the underlying VPC that Vercel internally uses. Because of this limitation you will not be able to build a VPC to VPC peering.

That being said; DynamoDB [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/) for Egress will be about $0.09 / GB billed at a monthly basis. So if you read 1 GB of data from DynamoDB apart from the Read and Write request units you will be charged $0.09 x Number of GBs data transfer out from DynamoDB.

For in-depth analysis on your data transfer; I strongly encourage that you enable AWS Cost and Usage report and look at the [raw data gathered](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/cur-data-transfers-charges.html) by it. You can also use AWS Cost Explorer for the sam purpose.